# unable to get selected (Key) value of that dropdownlist that is binded using Ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery

I have successfully binded asp.net dropdownlist using ajax and jquery but 
  unable to get selected value of that dropdownlist to bind another dropdown
  Here's the different code i have tried but not getting required key value 
  these all are giving text value.

```
        var ddl = document.getElementById("<%=ddlKit.ClientID%>").value;
        alert(ddl);
        var vall = $jq183("[id*='ddlKit']").find('option:selected').val();
        alert(vall);
```

ServerSideCode

```
 [WebMethod]  

 public static ArrayList GetKitDrop(int OrderId)
    {
        Controller.Pharmacy.PHM001C OBJPHM001 = new 
        Controller.Pharmacy.PHM001C();
        var List11 = OBJPHM001.GetKit(categoryId);
        List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> List = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        var query1 = (from t in List11 select new { t.KIT_ID, t.KIT_NAME });
        List = query1.AsEnumerable().Select(item => new KeyValuePair<string, 
        string>(item.KIT_ID, item.KIT_NAME)).ToList();

        ArrayList arr_list = new ArrayList(List);
        return arr_list;
    }
```

Jquery

```
 $jq183("[id*='ddlOrder']").live('change', function (e) 
  {
      $jq183.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "PHM001.aspx/GetKitDrop",
            data: "{OrderId:'" + $(this).val() + "' }",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
            var ddlKit = $jq183("[id*=ddlKit]");
            ddlKit.empty().append('<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select</option>');
                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    ddlKit.append('<option>' + data.d[i].Value + '</option>');
                }
           },
            failure: function () {
                alert("Failed!");
            }
        });
  });
```

Comment: Where in this you are unable to fetch the value?

Comment: 1) `live()` was deprecated a *long* time ago. Use the delegated signature of the `on()` method instead, and also make sure you're not using an outdated version of jQuery. You should be using 1.12 at least. Ideally 3.x, if you don't need legacy IE support. 2) Don't build your own JSON string. Just provide an object to `data` and it will encode the values for ytou

Comment: jquery is runing properly thats not a version issue .. i just cant get that key value that is current selected.. do u know why?

Comment: @void  here $jq183("[id*='ddlKit']").find('option:selected').val();

Comment: i am using jquery-1.8.3.min.js this version of jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get the selected value on the basis of value attribute in option, missed in dynamically created option in your case

Comment: can u please provide some details?

Comment: ddlKit.append('<option value='+data.d[i].Value+'>' + data.d[i].Value + '</option>');

Comment: still getting text not value